# Field abc has changed type from DATETIME to TIMESTAMP

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql, google-bigquery

**Goal**: Loading parquet file in GCS bucket to BigQuery.
I have a transformed parquet file with a column datatype as "TIMESTAMP"(converted using Apache Spark sql). The datatype of the column in target table in BigQuery is "DATETIME". The data is a 'date and time without timezone'.

While loading this data to BigQuery, the following error is thrown:

```
    Caused by: com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.repackaged.com.google.cloud.bigquery.BigQueryException: 
    Provided Schema does not match Table table_name. Field abc has changed type from DATETIME to TIMESTAMP
        at com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.repackaged.com.google.cloud.bigquery.Job.reload(Job.java:411)
        at com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.repackaged.com.google.cloud.bigquery.Job.waitFor(Job.java:248)
        at com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.BigQueryWriteHelper.finishedJob$lzycompute$1(BigQueryWriteHelper.scala:153)
        at com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.BigQueryWriteHelper.finishedJob$1(BigQueryWriteHelper.scala:153)
        at com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.BigQueryWriteHelper.loadDataToBigQuery(BigQueryWriteHelper.scala:155)
        at com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.BigQueryWriteHelper.writeDataFrameToBigQuery(BigQueryWriteHelper.scala:90)
        ... 31 more
```

Comment: did you provide a schema when you load the data to bigquery?

Comment: Yes, @mck. I tried providing the schema but it still gives schema mismatch error
table_id="dataset.table"
    job_config = bigquery.LoadJobConfig(source_format=bigquery.SourceFormat.PARQUET)
    schema = [ 
        bigquery.SchemaField("LAST_UPDATE_DATE", "DATETIME"),
        bigquery.SchemaField("OTHER_COL", "STRING"),
        ....
    ]
    job_config.schema = schema
    uri = "gs://PATH/*.parquet"
    load_job = client.load_table_from_uri(
    uri, table_id, job_config=job_config
    )  # Make an API request.